# Cocos2d,Before submitting an app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

Do I have to have to put the images in the actual file of the project or can I have the images on the desktop? Also, is it normal when you archive a file to have a blank icon in the organizer. Appreciate any help I get.

Comment: i mean my sprite images.

Comment: ok, see my edit... I hope I am getting it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

About the images: when you build your app, all resources (images, sounds, etc) are copied into the app bundle, so it does not matter where they reside within your computer/project. On the other hand, it is a great advice to keep all you project files collected in a single place (not the Desktop...)

Usually the issue with a blank icon in the organizer comes from using "custom" icon names specified in your app info.plist. This is benign, but you might want to fix it by assigning the icons explicitly in Xcode summary pane for your target (see image)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your images should be included in the project folder for good organization; makes it easy to backup the folder and other projects when you know that everything needed in the project is inside this one folder.